# Reactjs: pass in variable to findDOMNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Running ES6 on top of Reactjs. Suppose I want to reference a node with firstName like this:

```
var el = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.firstName);
```

but `type = 'firstName'`. So I need to do something like this:

```
var el = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.{type});
```

And I've tried a handful of different variations and nothing works. I know the answer is very simple but I can't find it as I'm very much a newbie! I think this relates to string literals? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure i get what you mean by helped in the variable type. can you post what your `type` variable is? does `type` equal the string `'firstName'`, is it an object with key `type` etc?

Comment: Sure, just edited, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you want to make use of [javascripts bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) for accessing object properties

`this.refs[type]` instead of `this.refs.type`